# Keep screen ratio while maximizing mplayer

Tags: mplayer

I have a movie with a 1024x576 resolution while my screen resolution is 1280x800.

How can I keep the ratio of 1024/576 while MPlayer is stretched to the whole screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the switch `-monitoraspect 16:10`, or put `monitoraspect=16:10` into `~/.mplayer/config`

Comment: i'm not switching computers for now .. that's a working idea anyway

Comment: @hhaamu so if my screen resolution is 1600x900 as shared by xrandr and the movie is a 1920x800 or some other resolution, what should I do ?